# Low FPS on second monitor

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card

I have a [X550JX laptop](https://www.asus.com/us/Laptops/X550JX/specifications/) and i bought a monitor (XG2402), i was getting 100FPS on Overwatch with high settings but now i'm getting 30-59 FPS even when every video setting is LOW or OFF.

I wonder if it's running on my nvidia card or integrated graphics, in NVIDIA `Control Panel` > `3D` > `PhysX` both monitor and laptop display seems to be connected to the Intel HD Graphics and when i disable Intel HD Graphics driver i can't see anything on my monitor so i think it uses integrated graphics over NVIDIA.

Monitor is connected to my laptop using an HDMI cable.

How can I get it to use my GPU? (or is it already using it? if so, why is the fps too low?)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use dedicated video card instead of onboard?](https://superuser.com/questions/231446/how-to-use-dedicated-video-card-instead-of-onboard)

Comment: On notebooks with switchable graphics, displays are always connected to the low-power integrated graphics unit. They are hardwired this way. Dedicated graphics are connected to this display pipeline in a way that allows efficient injection of rendered images.

Comment: Have you opened High Performance mode in your laptop battery management?